# Status code that I don't understand - 302 / 200

Tags: http-status-code-302

I have a page that shows status codes that I cannot make sense of.

Basically if I go to domain/xxx/xxx I get 
- HTTP/1.1 302 Found domain/xxx and 
- HTTP/1.1 200 OK for domain/xxx/xxx

Why would this page show a 302 for another page if the actual page can be found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status Code 302 is meaning you redirected from a site to an other one.

Basicly if I understand you case it means you ping Url A which is not living anymore, but has a proxy to point to its new location. So you get 302 after hitting the url and 200 after you are moved to the current url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Actually it is the same website and more important both url are live. That is why I don't understand.
If I navigate to A why do I get a redirect to B before being served the actual page A. Should I not be immediately served page A?

Comment: It can be a loadbalancer/proxy issue. Or just the site is built like that.